# how to install ionic capacitor contact native plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native, ionic5

When i try to install "npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/contacts" in ionic 6, am getting error as follows

````
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@awesome-cordova-plugins%2fcontacts - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@awesome-cordova-plugins/contacts@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url. ```

how can i resolve this issue. same issue is happening for uid also.
````

Answer (score 1):

I think u have to use this one now:

https://github.com/capacitor-community/contacts

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/contacts

Comment: Yes, correct. It's preferred to use that repository (currently maintained by me) instead of the cordova one. Its codebase is cleaner, more up-to-date and better maintained. Moreover, it's specifically targeting Capacitor. Therefore the compatibility will be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the cordova-contacts-plugin repo [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#deprecation-notice), the cordova-contacts-plugin is deprecated since Nov 27, 2017.

As there is deprecation notice on [it's npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-contacts).

The plugin that is currently in the ionic docs is abandoned but it seems like ionic docs is not updated since then.

Comment: as this is capacitor project, cordova plugins not able to install

Comment: You're right. I edited the answer. Seems like there is an issue to fix the documentation : https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/issues/2613 But it's not resolved.

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/issues/3934#issuecomment-1000303856

Answer (score 0):

After installing dependencies you need to sync

```
ionic cap sync
```

then run your project. you see no error and successfully run

for more info about this plugin [click here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the individual cordova plugins (like contacts) with with @ionic-native/contacts and cordova-plugin-contacts